# Read pdf in iPad

Tags: ipad

I need to read pdf file on iPad. What i need is, read pdf with page turning animation, how can i do this. Please help with sample code.

Thanks

Comment: would need the same... any advices appreciated :) thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to an epub format but I don't know if that would do the animation